# NServicebus creates new logfile at each restart

Tags: file, logging, nservicebus

I think there must be an easy solution to my problem but I can't figure it out. We're using NServicebus in a windows service and we have configured it to use log4net for logging, in code we have this:

SetLoggingLibrary.Log4Net(log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator.Configure);

Configure.With().Log4Net().....

So far so good. The problem is that NServicebus still creates it's own logfile, named "logfile" placed the same folder the application is run in, i.e. amoung the binaries. In our development and test environments where we reinstall and restart the service frequently this soon polutes the binaries folder with a lot of logfiles as a new is created each day (the old one from a previous date is renamed to for instance: logfile2012-02-28).

In the config-file of the service we have these lines:

...

```
<section name="Logging" type="NServiceBus.Config.Logging, NServiceBus.Core" />
```

```
<Logging Threshold="OFF" />
```

so all logfiles are empty but how do we stop them from being created or at least have them created in a separate log folder?

Thanks

Christian

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your calls to SetLoggingLibrary and .Log4Net() are conflicting with each other, and probably also with the profiles (if you're using NServiceBus.Host.exe).

Have you looked through the docs?

http://docs.particular.net/nservicebus/logging/

Comment: Thank you, I have a better understanding of the logging now. My main question still remains though: using a Production profile - is there any way I can specify a separate folder for the logfiles? The documentation states that a max of 10 logfiles are created but that only seems true for a specific date. In our production env right now there are 22 logfiles, 10 of which are named logfile2012-01-26.xx . Bad configuration or do we have to implement our own profile/install without a profile to get rid of them?

Comment: You might look at creating your own profile which inherits from the NServiceBus Production profile and then configuring logging for that as described on this page: http://www.nservicebus.com/Profiles.aspx

Comment: updated link - http://docs.particular.net/nservicebus/hosting/nservicebus-host/logging-profiles